# React typescript interface only one of two required

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, interface

I was wondering how I can require one of the properties in the interface. I don't want to require both HideBelow and HideAbove but only one of them. How would I go about implementing that? There needs to be either below={HideBelow} or below={HideAbove} in the component.

```
<Example below={HideBelow} />
```

```
<Example below={HideAbove } />
```

```
interface TableContentProps {
    Data?: any;
    HideType: "above" | "below" | "none";
    HideBelow?: "sm" | "md" | "lg" | "xl";
    HideAbove?: "sm" | "md" | "lg" | "xs";
}
```